# How to change root directory to custom folder for webisite using laravel

Tags: web-services, laravel, web-hosting

I have created a website in Laravel and uploaded to a GoDaddy webserver.I uploaded projects to public_html folder using Filezilla. My project is under the folder name my_project in public_html folder.

If I type `www.example.com/` it shows forbidden error. But If I type `www.example.com/my_project/public` I can view my website. But I don't want to see this type url. How will I view my website by typing `www.example.com/`?

Comment: put all the files except index.php outside the public folder and change the path in index.php accordingly.

Comment: Why not point www.example.com to the folder /public_html/my_project/public as document root?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution....

Put  myproject folder without public folder in root directory.
Moved all files and folders in public folder to public_html folder.

Then editted /public_html/index.php file as

require **DIR**.'/../myproject/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../myproject/bootstrap/start.php';

and
editted myproject/bootstrap/path.php as

'public' => **DIR**.'/../../public_html'

now its works fine.